# Mac OS X ACL and file permissions

Tags: macos, file-permissions, acl

I'm trying to share a directory between 2 users, so that both have full access to it and to any files, and directories created within. Here are the things I've done so far:

1. Create a group for the 2 users (let's call it `group`)
2. Set directory group to `group`
3. Set the directory mode to 2770 (rwxrwx--- with sticky)
4. Add ACL entry `group allow add_file,delete,file_inherit,directory_inherit`

So I was expecting that everything works. However, some applications don't seem to recognize the ACL entry I've set. I've never really done anything with the umask yet, so directories are created in mode 0755 (not sure about files), with the ACL inherited, but when one user tries to create a new file inside a directory created by the other user, the system complains about file permissions. I've tested this with emacs. However, when I create a file using echo or just touch, there are no issues, and files are created. How do I solve this? Is there a way to set directory specific umask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out there's a permission for `add_subdirectory` so I added it to the ACE. This seems to have solved the issue.

You can check [Access Control Entries](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH8009?viewlocale=en_US) for permission precedence (this is documentation for Lion Server).